# Can't get Twitter gem to load - no such file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm running Ruby v1.8.7 and Rails v3.0.9.

I'm trying to use this twitter gem: http://twitter.rubyforge.org/, v1.7.0

The directions state you need to:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
LoadError
no such file to load -- twitter
```

I read on SO that the 1.7.0 gem isn't compatible with Ruby 1.8.7, so I downgraded to 0.9 (the version the SO answer mentioned was compatible with 1.8.x) and that still didn't work.

One thing that's weird is that if I fire up irb, and include rubygems first, I can include twitter with no problems.

I had to install the gem using sudo, but I don't think that should be the problem.

Any ideas how I can successfully include this twitter gem into my application?  It looks super easy to use, once I can get over this hurdle.

Update:  I tried adding

```
gem 'twitter'
```

to my Gemfile and ran bundle install, and now I get  a Phusion Passenger error:

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
Could not find twitter-1.7.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I was actually able to install twitter v.1.7.1

Other information I received from around the web that I'd need to downgrade to 0.9.0 turns out to be false.

I ran:

```
sudo gem list
```

And compared the versions of specific gems with what I found here:
https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/blob/master/HISTORY.md (I simply searched for the word 'dependency' to see which versions twitter cared about.

I also found this diff:
https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/commit/ac8114c1f6ba2da20c2267d3133252c2ffc6b6a3

And I compared the gems listed there with what I had installed, and I just made sure my system lined up with what I was seeing in the version notes.  Oftentimes what happened is that I had multiple versions of a gem, and for some reason, the lower version was taking precedence.

I'm not sure why I still have to add

```
gem 'twitter', '1.7.1'
```

to my Gemfile, but alas, that's the last step required in order to get this stuff working.

Phew!

Comment: I had to add the same. I'm going to look into why and post something later.

Answer (score 6):

you need to require the twitter gem in your Gemfile. Run bundle install, now check again.

```
gem 'twitter'
```

Comment: bummer, didn't work.  Now I'm getting a Phusion Passenger error, Could not find twitter-1.7.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound). I put gem 'twitter' inside my Gemfile, and ran bundle install.  Any other ideas?

Comment: ok, got it to work.  Not only did I need to put this in my Gemfile, but I also had to downgrade my twitter version I was using to 0.9.0.  Not sure if that's the highest version I can use with Ruby 1.8.7, but I'll check that out later.